# create ssh server on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ssh

I am a beginner ubuntu user and recently I wanted to create an ssh server on my desktop so I can access is when I'm at work through my macbook pro.

I've installed openssh

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

and I've checked my ipaddress using ifconfig. 
But when I try to ssh into it I keep getting the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

Also I am using xfinity and I've enabled port forwarding on my router. I've looked for tutorials on youtube and other forums but they were all tutorials using putty.

What do i need to do to make it work?

Comment: Make sure that you've installed `openssh-server`, as `openssh` isn't a package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your server (your desktop) temporary enable the password authentication. Open the ssh-server configuration

```
 sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and enable the password authentication

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Reload the configuration

```
sudo service ssh reload
```

Now you could login via ssh and password. If you want the key authentication, follow the *additionally* steps below.

---

On your client (MacBook), create a new key pair:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Copy your public key via `ssh-copy-id`

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -p 22 user@server
```

or as alternative

```
cat id_rsa.pub | ssh server cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

---

On your server (your desktop)

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and disable the password authentication

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Reload the configuration

```
sudo service ssh reload
```

Comment: how do i install ssh-copy-id to my mac?

Comment: No idea. That's Ubuntu and not Apple.